# How to get menu bar to appear on hover

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have an upper horizontal menu structure that when you hover over one of the menu items a pulldown sub-menu appears

see http://bit.ly/1gbKVYs

When you go to any other page in the site, you are able to hover over the Services menu item and the sub-menu dropdown appears.

The only time is does not is when you are on the Services landing page itself.

I would like to get the pulldown to apear when you are on the Services page iteself.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a `z-index` issue. On the hover, use:

```
z-index: 3 !important;
```

In the services page, for some reason, this following line takes in precedence:

```
ul#menu-main-menu li.current-menu-item ul.sub-menu {
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
```

You need to find that as it generates on the page and remove it.

Comment: It's unfortunate that `!important` is necessary.  I'd advise trying to cut it out of the `z-index: 1 !important;` rule.

Comment: @JosephMarikle That's a wordpress theme. Have a look at the original site.

Comment: Doubly unfortunate then. :P

Comment: thank you @PraveenKumar. I'l see what I find and post back